# Отсутствует перевод в результатах поиска по справке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, поиск

На [странице поиска по справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=GPT) отсутствует перевод для количества результатов:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил [переводы](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=a470e83c83ca065d42c755b797ddbfb5), которые могут здесь использоваться. Но 100% уверенности нет. Ждём следующую сборку для проверки. Текущая rev 2023.6.23.43509